# how to get word from string via regexpt

Tags: javascript, regex, get, substring

I have string and i need to get word from symbol till space for example:

```
 const str = "/count 50"
```

I need to get "count" from string. So I probably need to cut first symbol till first space.

Comment: what's wrong with matching first match of `[a-zA-Z]+`?

Comment: may be `str.replace(/[\d]+/,"");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var r = '/count 50'.match(/\/([A-Za-z]+)/)[1];

console.log(r)
```

Comment: this would remove empty space too

Comment: @Muhammad Omer Aslam "get word from symbol till space". Am I missing something?

Comment: i think "till space?" or maybe not? otherwise he should have said word.

Comment: @S.Kablar Thank you bro

Answer (score 1):

Use the `substring` function.

**As you've stated:** *I need to get word from **symbol** till space*

```js
let str = "/count 50";

console.log(str.substring(str.indexOf('/'), str.indexOf(' ')))
```

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam can you explain why?

Comment: i think he does not want the `/` in the resulting string, as he said **get word after `/`** , just notifying cuz there are many users on SO who find it amusing to downvote others for small mistakes

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam the OP states: *I need to get word from **symbol** till space*, it's clear.

Comment: read again the last line **How i can get word after "/" if i dont know words length?**

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I know, but that's against the first statement. So, my answer follows the first statement.  However, thank you.

Comment: @Ele "get word after `/` "

Comment: @S.Kablar the OP is confused about his/her question.  **My answer does what was asked according to:** *I need to get word from **symbol** till space*

Comment: @Ele I'm sorry, I do not speak English very well and because of this there was a misunderstanding, I did not want to include the symbol in the result

Comment: @РомаБойко Ok ok, no problem :-)